# iOS 6.0 Facebook Connectivity

Tags: iphone

I have to get connected to the facebook on button click in iOS 6.0. I have added the frameworks social and accounts to my project. I am able to check in to a place but, not able to tag friends for what I am posting to the facebook. How to fetch facebook friends list?

The code I have used is shown below :

```
- (IBAction)connectToFacebook:(id)sender
{
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

NSDictionary *options = @{
@"ACFacebookAppIDKey": @"412590558803147",
@"ACFacebookAppVersionKey": @"1.0",
@"ACFacebookPermissionsKey": @"publish_stream",
@"ACFacebookPermissionGroupKey": @"write"
};

NSLog(@"options is %@",options);

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:options
                                        completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                            if (granted)
                                            {
                                                NSArray *accounts = [accountStore
                                                                     accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
                                            NSString *facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];

                                                NSLog(@"facebook account %@", facebookAccount);
                                            } else {
                                                NSLog(@"%@",error);
                                                // Fail gracefully...
                                            }
                                        }];

if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

    SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
        if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {

            NSLog(@"Cancelled");

        } else

        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Posted!!!" message:@"your status is posted to facebook successfully" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [alert show];
        }

        [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
    };
    controller.completionHandler =myBlock;

    [controller setInitialText:@"This is a ios 6.0 facebook intergration application"];
    [controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"spalshimage.jpeg"]];

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];

}
else{
    NSLog(@"UnAvailable");
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The best way to integrate Facebook is to use the new iOS 6 Facebook SDK:**

https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios6/

**Try this link for friend list:**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/show-friends/